# vb.net connect to MDF file without SQL Server installation

Tags: sql-server

can vb.net  connect to MDF file without SQL Server installation
I want to install this application to client machine without installing sql server

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain that the closest you can get to what are asking for is to use LocalDB -- which is available as an install option with SQL Server Express installation media.

LocalDB *by itself* should be sufficient to allow your app to connect to and query the MDF file.

LocalDB represents the lightest, most-minimal install that you could choose for your scenario.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15) describe what I am talking about in this way:

> LocalDB installation copies a minimal set of files necessary to start
> the SQL Server Database Engine. Once LocalDB is installed, you can
> initiate a connection using a special connection string.
>
> When connecting, **the necessary SQL Server infrastructure is automatically
> created and started, enabling the application to use the database
> without complex configuration tasks**. Developer Tools can provide
> developers with a SQL Server Database Engine that lets them write and
> test Transact-SQL code **without having to manage a full server instance
> of SQL Server.**

Comment: As long as data files don't exceed 10Gb in total, that is. Then again, at this point it would be prudent to invest into a dedicated server (of at least Standard Edition), possibly in Azure, not to mention having backups already set up.